# How to select the dropdown value by default according to data retured in JQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to select the dropdown value by default according to data returned in JQuery datatable. I am using the following code: **mySite.js**

```
"columns": [
           {"data":"NAME"},

           { "data": null, 
             "defaultContent":'<Select id="cls" ><option>--SELECT---</option><option>I</option><option II</option><option>III</option><option >IV</option><option>V</option><option ></select>'},
                      { 
          "data": "COMMENTS",
           "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
           if (type == 'display') {
           return '<textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="2" cols="25" maxlength="2000" wrap="hard" style ="resize:none;">'+ data + '</textarea>';
                 }
        return data
         } 
        },]
```

How to use render function for the Select tag to select the option according to the data returned.

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,this will fix your issue

```
"render": function(d,t,r){
        var $select = $("<select></select>", {
            "id": r[0]+"start",
            "value": d
        });
        $.each(times, function(k,v){
            var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                "text": v,
                "value": v
            });
            if(d === v){
                $option.attr("selected", "selected")
            }
            $select.append($option);
        });
        return $select.prop("outerHTML");
    }
```

Comment: But I have to display select box in every row of the datatable

Comment: @Aishwarya..have you tried with this                                                                   For more details refer this jsfiddle link                                                                      https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/kt82jqsf/